# IIS 7 Manager can't write to web.config

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config, iis-manager

Everytime I try to add / update settings through the IIS 7 Manager I get the following error.

[image]

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate (32-bit). I'm using a LocalSystem AppPoolIdentity

Comment: Did you find a solution to this error?

Comment: @chobo We have exactly [this issue](https://danielsmon.com/2017/04/03/cant-write-to-applicationhost-config/), same error message as above. We've resorted to disabling EFS on certain config files to get around it but that doesn't solve the core issue: on most of our servers editing a EFS "web.config" file though IIS works fine (assuming you have the right user account setup in the App pool), but on one specific server it does not, would love to know the reason why.

Answer (score 4):

Check if web.config has read only permissions checked.

Comment: I checked and it has full permissions :(

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the web.config's Read-only FILE attribute is not checked:

[image: web.config file properties]

Answer (score 2):

This error can also happen if the hard drive has run out of space - i.e. there isn't enough space to write the to the config file.

Obviously this would have to be a very full drive, but I've seen this happen on servers where the log files are written to the C drive (and evetually fill it right up)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the location of your webconfig file has the correct security permissions set.  Normally giving the IIS_IUSRS group permission to the directory works.

Comment: I added that user with full control to the directory and it still throws that error :(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Copy web.config file from original to alternate location, e.g.,
   Desktop
2. Edit and save in alternate location
3. Copy back to original location

I do not understand why this works, but it did for me and apparently several other users.